# How to find sublist (intersection) among items in one Arraylist of integer in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `Hashtable<List<Integer>, List<Triples>> ResultIPM2 = new HashTable<>()`, I want to work on the key part which is a`List<Integer>`contains three patterns {[2,3,4] , [3,2,4,3] , [2,4,3]}.What I want to do is, I want to remove [2,4,3] because it is a subset of [3,2,4,3]. How can I report just [2,4,3] and [3,2,4,3] .

Note that the intersection must be in the same order as the smaller list.

For example, if instead of [3,2,4,3] we had a pattern [3,2,3,4] we wouldn't remove any pattern. by "remove" I mean not showing the pattern when reporting it.Here is a piece of my code: 
 Please don't care about the other answers because I had to edit this old question in order to be able to ask a new question.Thank you

```
    Set<List<Integer>> key = resultsIPM2.keySet();
    boolean maximal = false;
    for(List<Integer> p1  : key){
        for(List<Integer> p2:key){
         if(!p2.equals(p1)){
             if(p1.containsAll(p2)){
                 System.out.println(p1);
             }
         }   
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the enhanced for loop to remove from the list. Use an explicit Iterator.

```
List<List<Pair>> newPattern = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();         
     //Algorithm : end of Line 14
        Iterator<List<Pair> iter = ptList.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
          List<Pair> list = iter.next();
          Iterator<Pair> pairIter = list.iterator();
          while(pairIter.hasNext()){ 
             Pair pair = pairIter.next();

             if (getFrequency(pair) < minSupp){
                 pairIter.remove();
                 newPattern.add(list);
             }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Actually I did something like this and I edited the question to provide the code which I used explicit Iterator . I will try your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Iterator.remove()` is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration.

Use `Iterator` instead of the `for-each` construct when you need to remove the current element.

`The for-each` construct hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove. Therefore, the `for-each` construct is not usable for filtering.

Now regarding the code which you said dint work is because

```
Iterator <Pair> iter = pairList.iterator();
```

should be something like this

```
Iterator<List<Pair> iter = ptList.iterator();
```

then again when you do `iter.next();`
It will give you `List<Pair> list` not this `Pair pair`. So you need to iterate over the list again the compare and remove.

*Eran* gave you a very nice example follow that

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify a List while you are in a foreach loop of this list. You can use a normal for-loop which just increments an `int` to get your element:

```
List<List<Pair>> newPattern = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();         
//Algorithm : end of Line 14
for(int i = 0; i < ptList.size(); i++){
    List<Pair> list = ptList.get(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){ 
         Pair pair = list.get(j);
         if (getFrequency(pair) < minSupp){
             list.remove(j);
             j--;
             newPattern.add(list);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case you have to be careful with the indices. When you call list.remove(j), the elements following the j'th element move to the left, so the j+1 element becomes the new j'th element. Therefore, you shouldn't increment the loop index when you remove a Pair from the list. Otherwise you'll skip the next member of the list in the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Eran what if the pairs where stored in a `List<Pair>` not `List<List<Pair>>` can you give me a modified code for that?

Comment: @Hk148 In that case you will have just a single while loop, which looks like the code in my answer starting in the line `Iterator<Pair> pairIter = list.iterator();`

Comment: @Eran Thanks for pointing this out, i forgot a line of code. Added this line.

Comment: @Eran thanks for that , but now my output gives me the duplicate values which I don't need them. for a minSupp=5 for example the output is:[(3,28), (3,28), (3,28)] but in fact it should return onw (3,28).

Comment: @Hk148 Try using a `Set` instead of a `List`, a Set can hold every value only once

Comment: @user3755692 I can't use a `Set` now because the pairs are stored in a `List` and if there was three (3,28) pairs in one index like [(3,28),(3,28), (3,28)] the `Set` considers what is in the bracket as one item that's why it won't delete the duplicates .

Comment: @Eran I didn't write that method, the OP said that this method exists

Comment: @Hk148 Please show your getFrequency method. Perhaps your problem lies there.

Comment: This is my `getFrequency` method:
    `public int getFrequency(Pair pair){
        int minSupp=0;
        int frequency = 0;
        List<Pair> ptList = getPairList();
            for(Pair listpair : ptList){
                if(pair.getX()== listpair.getX() && pair.getY() == listpair.getY()){
                    frequency += 1;
                }
            }
        return frequency;
    }`

Comment: @user3755692 Sorry about that, I meant that comment to the OP.